# Maximum Likelihood & Least Squares Method with and without given errors

Tags: probability, statistics

In our lecture we used ML and LS to estimate the parameter(s) of a given distribution. In both examples we had we were given three measurements $y_i$. For the LS method we also had an error $\sigma_i$ for each measurement. Now I think the LS method we used is also called weighted least squares as the function we sought to minimize was given by:

$S(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(y_i-f(x_i,a))^2}{\sigma_i^2}$

For the error on the parameter estimate we varied $S(a)$ so that the difference between $S(a_{min})$ and the new $S(a)$ is $n^2$ to get the $n \sigma$ standard deviation for $a$.  Now I got this but here is my first question: What do I do if no errors for my measurements are given?

Secondly we had a very similar example for the Maximum Likelihood method, again with three measurements. But in this case no errors were given. So I know how to compute the parameter estimate but if errors were given I had no idea how to incorporate them in my likelihood function $L$. For the error of the parameter estimate we varied $L$ again (as in LS) so the difference would be $\pm 0.5/2/3.4$ for $1/2/3\sigma$. I would assume there is a reasonable way to include errors somehow. But how?

Answer (score 0):

At least the first case you have two probabilities:

First you assume a fixed error that is the same for each point. A reasonable pick would have to be justified from the particular case.

Second you assume that the measurement itself was exact. This can also be justified, e.g. when the error is very small and you have lots of data points or when the measurement outcomes are discrete or just because you do have no better possibility. Then you simply set $\sigma=1$

Does this answer your first question?

Comment: Ok I see! For our examples we only ever had small data sets (i.e. less than 10 measurements). In that case I guess there is no canonical way to determine the error. This would then answer my first question. Since the second question is still open I will not mark your answer as the accepted answer yet but upvote it for now. Thank you very much!

Comment: you must not mix up the error of your final fit/regression with the error of each measurement point. The latter is determined by how you get your data, i.e. some physical experiment. As long as it is a math exercise you really just have to assume that there is no error in the individual datapoints. 

The error of your fit depends on how good your model is.

Comment: Check. I just thought that maybe in certain cases there would be something people do. Like assume you were to fit your data with a poisson distribution, then you would - without having any given errors on your measurements - assume your measurement are like that which are expected for a poisson. (I know these errors would depend on the mean which you were to determine by this very procedure but maybe then there is some iterative process one would do or something). But it makes sense to just assume the measurements to be exact without further knowledge. Thanks!